# Ionic/Angular Multiple filter in child array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've to filter this array:

```
Ricette: [{
    "id":"1",
    "title":"Pasta al pomodoro",
    "ings":{"id":["1","2","3"]}
}, {
    "id":"2",
    "title":"Spaghetti alla carbonara",
    "ings":{"id":["1","2","4","5","6"]}
}]
```

And i need to filter it by `ings` selected from a checkboxes

`ings` list:

```
[{"id":"1","nome":"Olio"},
{"id":"2","nome":"Pasta"},
{"id":"3","nome":"Passata di pomodoro"},
{"id":"4","nome":"Parmigiano"},
{"id":"5","nome":"Uova"},
{"id":"6","nome":"Pancetta"}]
```

Template:

```
 <div ng-repeat="ing in ingredienti">
      <b><input type="checkbox">{{ing.nome}}</b>
    </div>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="ricetta in ricette" href="#/app/ricette/{{ricetta.id}}">
        {{ricetta.title}}
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-list>
```

How i can filter "ricette" list by the selected checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You need a way of tracking which checkboxes are actually checked. I would go with 'ng-model' like so:

```
   <div ng-repeat="ing in ingredienti">
      <b><input type="checkbox" ng-model="ing.checked">{{ing.nome}}</b>
    </div>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="ricetta in ricette" href="#/app/ricette/{{ricetta.id}}">
        {{ricetta.title}}
      </ion-item> 
    </ion-list>
```

Then your filter would be something like: `ingredienti | filter:{checked:true}`